# When converting the pdf table to Excel, how can I make it into a single file?

Tags: python, excel

Converting the tables in the pdf into Excel with the script below has succeeded, but there is a problem that too many individual xlsx files are generated. Is there any way to create a single xlsx file?

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd

df = tabula.read_pdf('~/data.pdf', pages = 'all')
for i in range(len(df)):
 df[i].to_excel('file_'+str(i)+'.xlsx')
```